# Python 3 Sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I'm working with a small script that creates a listening socket and receives a file from a client.

This code works in python 2.7 but I cannot figure out why it doesn't work with python 3. Can someone help me make this work?

```
import socket

(HOST, PORT) = ('', 19129)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT));
s.listen(1);
conn, addr = s.accept()

with open('LightData.txt', 'wb') as f:
    while True:
        t = conn.recv(20)
        print (t)
        if t == "":
            s.close()
            break

        f.write(t)
```

It gets stuck somewhere at `if t==:`, because in the console it keeps printing

```
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

Comment: Try this in an interactive interpreter: `b'' == ""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python2:

```
>>> b'' == ''
True
```

In python3:

```
>>> b'' == ''
False
```

So replace `if t == "":` with `if t == b'':`

Comment: Something is still not right, after replacing with what you had suggested the console returns,  "b'1\n'
b''

Process finished with exit code 0
" i am expecting it to return either a 1 or a 0 as the data i'm receiving and put it in the text file LightData.txt

Comment: It was working after doing what you had mentioned i had been using a temporary directory in PyCharm...That's why it did not update the file. thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if t == "":
```

Your `t` is binary data, a `bytes` object. No `bytes` object is ever equal to a Unicode `str` object. So this will always fail. Try it yourself:

```
>>> b'' == ''
False
```

The reason this worked in Python 2 is that byte-strings and strings were the same type, while `unicode` strings were a different type. In Python 3, Unicode strings and strings are the same type, while `bytes` are a different type.

---

If you'd written this the idiomatic way in Python 2, it would continue to work in Python 3:

```
if not t:
```

In Python, you usually just check whether a value is "truthy" or "falsey". A non-empty string and a non-empty byte-string are both truthy; empty ones are both falsey. The only time you want to write a check like `if t == ""` is when you explicitly want to check *only* empty strings, and have it fail for `None`, or `False`, or empty bytestrings.